# Verizon Samsung Galaxy S4 root reverts on reboot

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm trying to root my Verizon Samsung Galaxy S4 (i545 vruame7) and install cyanogenmod.

I've followed [this](http://galaxys4root.com/galaxy-s4-root/how-to-root-for-verizon-galaxy-s4-on-build-vruame7/) how-to and it seems to work for the current session.  However, when I try to install cyanogenmod via ROM manager it fails after rebooting.  I don't get any error messages either then a dead android with an exclamation mark.  Also, I don't get the usual unlocked boot screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install CWM with the Loki method? Have you tried installing CM from CWM?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  I tried installing it by using the ROM manager.  The first step of this was to install ClockworkMod recovery.  Which seems to have worked (it didn't visibly fail at least).  Is there another method I can use?  Could you post a link that I can try?

Comment: It's a follow-up link in your own source link, [here](http://galaxys4root.com/galaxy-s4-root/how-to-install-cwm-recovery-on-att-or-verizon-galaxy-s4-sgh-i337sch-i545/)